# Mutt seems to sync to Gmail IMAP only on quit

Tags: gmail, gmail-imap, mutt

I am using Mutt 1.5.20 in Mac OS X Terminal. I have a Google mail account whose mail I fetch via IMAP. I also use a Gmail notifier app to notify me of new e-mail messages. My experience with Mutt dates no later than 1 week.

**The trouble is this**: When my Gmail notifier tells me about a new e-mail, I hit the Terminal to open Mutt. I can read the message and Mutt will mark it as *read*. However, Google's servers are not told that the message is read *until Mutt is closed*. Thus, my Gmail notifier continues to show a misleading unread count.

How can I force Mutt to synchronize with IMAP without having to quit every time I finish reading my e-mail? Preferably the sync will occur instantaneously, but a periodic sync would be satisfactory as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Manual syncing

Try <kbd>$</kbd>:

```
$         sync-mailbox         save changes to mailbox
```

### Automatic syncing?

You can't make `mutt` do that automatically/periodically, by design. The reasoning, as I understand it, is that it might lead to data loss. E.g., when you mark something as deleted, you'd normally be able to undo, and auto-syncing would interfere with that (see [Re: Auto sync-mailbox - no way!](http://www.mail-archive.com/mutt-users@mutt.org/msg29460.html) and [Mutt, IMAP and auto'refresh'](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/mutt-imap-and-autorefresh-840317/)).

Mailboxes should be synced in any case when you change folders/mailboxes.

### Alternatives

There's a [source patch adding a timeout-hook to mutt](http://wolfermann.org/mutt.html) you could use to periodically call `sync-mailbox`, but it's for `mutt 1.5.9` and I don't know if it can be applied against the current version.

You could also set up [OfflineIMAP](https://github.com/nicolas33/offlineimap) (or [isync](http://isync.sourceforge.net/)). It's designed for synchronizing local mailbox(es) with a central IMAP one. You can then use another notification system (like e.g. `mutt`'s built-in one or `mail-notification` etc.) to watch your local box for changes.

Comment: This is good. Shamefully I hadn't noticed this before. However, the question now is: How can mutt be taught to do this periodically?

Comment: Another alternative approach is to simply add <sync-mailbox> to any macros you use frequently, like changing folders or viewing messages or something.